# cxgrid column filter option "between"

Tags: delphi, devexpress, delphi-xe4

I have a column that is a "date" type. How can I have the option "between" in custom option ?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Note that you have 2 boxes.
`between` (in SQL) is all inclusive so set box 1 to: `DATE >= startdate` and box 2 to `DATE <= enddate`.

Comment: There is an option to set the "between" option in the filter. I have done it some time ago but now I forgot. It is much better and easier with the 'between' option.